# Unable to import python package in vs-code but, no issues in terminal

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to use https://github.com/uber/orbit.  I have the package installed without errors as far as I can see.

I can run everything just fine in my terminal on my mac.  However, I load up vs-code and try and run there and I receive the error below.    I can't figure out what the problem is or how to configure my vs-code to avoid this issue.

This causes the following error.  NO issues in terminal.
from orbit.utils.dataset import load_iclaims
from orbit.models import DLT
from orbit.diagnostics.plot import plot_predicted_data

My python version is 3.9.15 that I am running this in both in terminal and in vs-code.
If anyone has an idea, can you please be specific on steps on how to fix this, as I have been hunting in vscode for a while and can't figure it out why I don't have this issue in terminal, but only in VSCODE

```
OperationalError                          Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[3], line 1
----> 1 from orbit.models import DLT

File ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/orbit/__init__.py:3
      1 __all__ = ["satellite", "tle", "utilities"]
----> 3 from .satellite import satellite

File ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/orbit/satellite.py:3
      1 from math import degrees
----> 3 from . import tle, utilities
      5 class satellite:
      6     def __init__(self,catnr):

File ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/orbit/tle.py:10
      6 import ephem
      8 from . import utilities
---> 10 requests_cache.install_cache(expire_after=86400)
     12 def get(catnr):
     13     page = html.fromstring(requests.get('http://www.celestrak.com/cgi-bin/TLE.pl?CATNR=%s' % catnr).text)

File ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests_cache/patcher.py:48, in install_cache(cache_name, backend, expire_after, urls_expire_after, allowable_codes, allowable_methods, filter_fn, stale_if_error, session_factory, **kwargs)
     23 def install_cache(
     24     cache_name: str = 'http_cache',
...
--> 168     self._local_context.con = sqlite3.connect(self.db_path, **self.connection_kwargs)
    169     if self.fast_save:
    170         self._local_context.con.execute('PRAGMA synchronous = 0;')

OperationalError: unable to open database file
```

Comment: This looks more like a file path error related to finding your sqllite database rather than an import error.

Comment: How do you execute scripts in the terminal without problems? And how to execute the script in vscode? Can you show detailed information? Also check that the correct interpreter is being used.